# Can't adjust brightness i find a answer but its say a error

Tags: grub2, brightness

I can't adjust the contrast on my laptop dell and I found this on this site:

> Open the terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and type:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Change the line:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
> ```
>
> Save and exit the file.
>
> Now in the terminal type:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Restart your Linux.

But when I type `sudo update-grub` it says:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a closing double quote in that line. Please check for that.

If not, this [well-written page](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/11/how-to-set-display-brightness-in-ubuntu-12-04-login-screen-in-hp-laptops/) should help you out. While it is written for HP, the procedure should work for any laptops. It is a common procedure for linux kernel.